# Using an image node as Point Distribute density in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wanted to try replicating the Pastiche After Effects plugin inside Blender, and starting off I wanted to distribute some points on a plane, and limit where they can be with an image node, either with the alpha or with the color.
When I plug any input into the point distribute node all the points disappear and I don't really know why. Am I missing something?

[image: Before plugging in the image node]

[image: After plugging in the image node]

Just to be safe, an [introduction to the Pastiche plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aiyj0gJBFbk), as a reference

**EDIT**: I tried with other images and through a Color Ramp, and now it sorta works? The problem is that the result is nowhere near the original image, so now the question is: **Is there some sort of "Mapping" node in Geometry Nodes?**

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that domain, that gets information from texture, is very low - it has only 4 points (since it is a plane with 4 vertexes).

If you increase the number of points, for example using subdivision, you will get proper results:

[image]

Subdivide either in edit mode or in GN:

[image]

But you might think increasing the number of polygons is a bad idea. So this is a more clever method. Instead of using texture before generation, use it after it. So that domain will have the size of each generated point.

Sharp threshold:

[image]

Softer threshold:

[image]