# How can I use image texture to mask point instancing in Geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, masking

I have digital elevation terrain with image texture. I want to instance trees on the green channel of texture. I already isolate the Green Channel in photoshop and make it black and white as a mask. Now I don't know how to instance trees on that terrain base on texture mask. Hope that explain my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any issue plug image (mask) into Selection?

[image]
[image]

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247312) is another way.