# Scatter objects in geometry nodes using rgb mask?

Tags: geometry-nodes

So I've painted in textures using RGB mask and now I only want to scatter grass or bushes on the green channel of the mask.
I tried just plugging the image texture with the mask into a separate color to the selection but yeah, I kinda knew that wouldn't work :)

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using an image node as Point Distribute density in Geometry Nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247312/using-an-image-node-as-point-distribute-density-in-geometry-nodes)

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this as follows:

[image]

There are only two things to be aware of:

1. Your *UV Map* must be used in *Geometry Nodes* as a basis for correct positioning.
2. You must in some way convert these values into a selection, or use them as a control for the density of the distribution.

There are already some good examples here of how to solve this, so I've presented it a little differently here.

I use here as base for the node `Image Texture` (in which your texture will be loaded) the *UV Map* I created before, on which some areas are painted in green.

With a `Math` node I multiply the green channel (adjust this multiplication according to your wishes) to bring it into a higher range.

Now you could directly create a selection with a `Compare` node, but here I chose the `Random Value` node (set to *Boolean*) so that I can achieve a smoother transition.

Finally I use this selection to remove the points that are not needed.

---

Of course you also have the possibility to use the values of the green channel directly in the node `Distribute Points on Faces` at the input *Density*. However, for this the mesh must be available in a sufficiently high resolution.

Technically this variant would be preferable, because you don't have to create points first, which are then removed again (less overhead), but the distribution is also primarily influenced by the mesh topology.

For this reason, I chose this variant here, as it is not clear from your example what the topology of the mesh looks like.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.4+, but with small changes usable from 3.2)*</sub>